# Write V_final in terms of V1

Tags: ac, diodes

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcEgA2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Being \$V_1=10\sin(100t)\$ and \$V_D=0.7\$V, it is asked to find the output potential as a function of \$V_1\$.

I made:
 $$-V_1+10\text{k}\Omega \times I=V_{\text{final}}=-10\text{k}\Omega \times I-5.7$$

and gives me \$9.9995\sin(100t)-0.000215\$.

However, in Multisim I got the following graph:

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Where is V_final? What equation are you using to find I? Why are you using V_1 = 20 Vpk when your equation says that the maximum is 10V?

Comment: @Gregg d'Eon the question says V_1 = 20 Vpk and i read V_1 = 20 Vpk-pk. Thanks. Can you write an answer so that i can see the correct way to think?

Comment: Hmm. I would interpret that as the peak voltage. Let me take a shot at an answer.

Comment: yes...i think you are write and that way the maximuns are explained but i don't know how to solve for minimums

Comment: I ran my own simulation of this circuit - the plot is in my answer. I don't know what the problem is with yours, but it looks off.

Comment: Even the simulation output looks wrong because the + probe is connected to ground. So the display is inverted.

Comment: That's it! I didn't notice that the top was "squashed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned to solve these diode-related problems like this.

First, I'll re-draw your schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr6S2d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then, look at two cases separately:

1) D1 is off (not conducting), so the voltage across the diode is less than 0.7 V

No current goes through R1, so \$V_{out} = V_1\$. The voltage across the diode is

\$ V_{D1} = -5V - V_{out} < 0.7V\$

so

\$ V_1 > -5.7 V\$

2) D1 is on (conducting). We know from case 1 that \$V_1 < -5.7V\$.

Taking KVL around the circuit and guessing (correctly) that current moves counterclockwise, we get

\$V_1 + 5V + 0.7V + (20kΩ)I  = 0\$

so

\$I = - \frac{V_1 + 5.7V}{20kΩ}\$

and the output voltage is

\$V_{out} = V_1 + IR_1 
= V_1 - (10kΩ)\frac{V_1 + 5.7V}{20kΩ}
= \frac{1}{2}V_1 - 2.85V\$

I simulated this circuit in LTSpice. Here is a plot of \$V_{1}(t)\$ and \$V_{out}(t)\$:

[image: Circuit sim results]
Notice that \$V_{out} = V_1\$ until \$V_1 < 5.7V\$, where it gets attenuated by the voltage divider of the two resistors.